# Why route on qnap is not working

Tags: routes, router, qnap

I have two networks, 172.16.4.0/22 and 172.16.16.0/22. There are two firewalls/GW

```
GW1: 172.16.4.1 & Internet 
GW2: 172 16.4.2 & 172.16.16.1
```

Behind GW2 are some spezial computer. I don´t like to use NAT on GW2, so each computer which likes to communicate with the 172.16.16.0/22 needs a route. I do this already on some Windows machines and this works fine:
Ständige Routen:

`Netzwerkadresse          Netzmaske  Gatewayadresse  Metrik
 172.16.16.0    255.255.252.0       172.16.4.2       1`

Actually i try to ping from a windows machine 172.16.19.5 a Qnap  172.16.4.10.

I added the following routes to qnap:

`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.4.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
172.16.4.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.16.16.0     172.16.4.2      255.255.252.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0`

1. From Qnap 172.16.4.10 i can ping the Windows machine 172.16.19.5
2. From the windows machine 172.16.19.5 i can´t ping the qnap 172.16.4.10
3. If i enable NAT on gw2 all works fine

I can´t see my problem. Is there a mistake in adding the route to the qnap?

I already checkt the firewall log, there is nothing blocking. On a windows machine the ping is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

which NAS you used ?
may need to check the tutorial about NVS: Network Virtual Switch

https://www.qnap.com/en/how-to/tutorial/article/how-to-use-and-set-up-your-network-virtual-switch